# Always show tags for a header file in tagbar

Tags: c++, vim, tagbar

I'm using vim with tagbar plugin and by default tagbar shows tags for the current active buffer. I'm curious if there is an option to make it always show tags for the corresponding header file. So for example if the current buffer is *foo.cpp* I want tagbar to show tags for *foo.hpp* or *foo.h*. Is there such an option in tagbar or I have to code it myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version 2.5, there is a `:TagbarTogglePause` command that allows you to view the header tags while editing the implementation file (and vice versa). Have you checked the documentation - I don't think your feature is mentioned?!

In any case, you should probably file an enhancement request at the [plugin's GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/issues), offer to implement this, and coordinate with the plugin author to increase the chances of your patch becoming accepted.